# Sound Output Device selection has no effect if USB headset is plugged in

Tags: gnome, usb, sound, pulseaudio

The gnome sound settings work as expected as long as I don't plug in my USB headset (Logitech H650e): I can switch between the available output devices without problems. When I plug in the USB headset, this is automatically chosen as input and output device, which is still expected behaviour. However, now, selecting a different output device has no effect, and the sound always comes from the headset. The input device selection works fine.

I tried with pavucontrol as well. Here I can see the different configurations, but the sound is always coming through the USB headset.

Please let me know if you need more information than what reported below.

Details:
Ubuntu version 20.04.1
Gnome Version 3.36.3

```
pacmd list-cards | grep 'active profile'
active profile: <input:analog-stereo>
active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
```

(the headset does not show up here)

The gnome settings shows me four devices:

- Headphones - Logitech Stereo H650e
- Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Logitech Stereo H650e
- Speakers - Built-in audio
- HDMI / DisplayPort - Built-in audio

No matter which I choose, running the test I always get the sound through the headphones.
If I unplug the headphones, I only see the last two devices, and I can choose between the internal speakers of the desktop, and the speakers in my DisplayPort monitor.

```
lsusb:
...
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 046d:0a46 Logitech, Inc. Logitech Stereo H650e

lspci:
...
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
```

Comment: Struggling with the same problem, but with HDMI. Did you fix your problem?